# New Relic causing uninitialized constant Mongoid::Collection (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, newrelic

After moving my Heroku app to Unicorn, New Relic stopped showing any reports except for deployments. I tried the solution suggested here: https://newrelic.com/docs/ruby/no-data-with-unicorn with no luck. I tried updating all gems, and now I get the error:

> Exiting
>   /Users/bashar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-preview1@global/gems/rpm_contrib-2.1.11/lib/rpm_contrib/instrumentation/mongoid.rb:13:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>': uninitialized constant Mongoid::Collection (NameError)
>           from /Users/bashar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-preview1/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.6.0.83/vendor/gems/dependency_detection-0.0.1.build/lib/dependency_detection.rb:53:in`call'
>           from /Users/bashar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-preview1/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.6.0.83/vendor/gems/dependency_detection-0.0.1.build/lib/dependency_detection.rb:53:in `block in execute'
>           from /Users/bashar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-preview1/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.6.0.83/vendor/gems/dependency_detection-0.0.1.build/lib/dependency_detection.rb:52:in`each'
>           from /Users/bashar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-preview1/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.6.0.83/vendor/gems/dependency_detection-0.0.1.build/lib/dependency_detection.rb:52:in `execute'
>           from /Users/bashar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-preview1/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.6.0.83/vendor/gems/dependency_detection-0.0.1.build/lib/dependency_detection.rb:19:in`block in detect!'
>           from /Users/bashar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-preview1/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.6.0.83/vendor/gems/dependency_detection-0.0.1.build/lib/dependency_detection.rb:17:in `each'
>           from /Users/bashar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-preview1/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.6.0.83/vendor/gems/dependency_detection-0.0.1.build/lib/dependency_detection.rb:17:in`detect!'
>           from /Users/bashar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-preview1/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.6.0.83/lib/new_relic/control/instrumentation.rb:93:in `_install_instrumentation'
>           from /Users/bashar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-preview1/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.6.0.83/lib/new_relic/control/instrumentation.rb:52:in`install_instrumentation'
>           from /Users/bashar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-preview1/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.6.0.83/lib/new_relic/control/instance_methods.rb:76:in `init_plugin'
>           from /Users/bashar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-preview1/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.6.0.83/lib/newrelic_rpm.rb:40:in`block in '
>           from /Users/bashar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-preview1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
>           from /Users/bashar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-preview1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in`run'
>           from /Users/bashar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-preview1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
>           from /Users/bashar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-preview1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in`each'
>           from /Users/bashar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-preview1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
>           from /Users/bashar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-preview1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in`initialize!'
>           from /Users/bashar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-preview1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
>           from /Users/bashar/rails-projects/myapp/config/environment.rb:5:in`'
>           from /Users/bashar/rails-projects/myapp/config.ru:7:in `block in <main>'
>           from /Users/bashar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-preview1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in`instance_eval'
>           from /Users/bashar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-preview1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
>           from /Users/bashar/rails-projects/myapp/config.ru:1:in`new'
>           from /Users/bashar/rails-projects/myapp/config.ru:1:in `<main>'
>           from /Users/bashar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-preview1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in`eval'
>           from /Users/bashar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-preview1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
>           from /Users/bashar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-preview1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in`app'
>           from /Users/bashar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-preview1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
>           from /Users/bashar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-preview1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:301:in`wrapped_app'
>           from /Users/bashar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-preview1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:252:in `start'
>           from /Users/bashar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-preview1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in`start'
>           from /Users/bashar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-preview1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
>           from /Users/bashar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-preview1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in`tap'
>           from /Users/bashar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-preview1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
>           from script/rails:6:in`require'
>           from script/rails:6:in `'

I have the following gems in order:

```
gem 'rpm_contrib'
gem 'newrelic_rpm'
gem 'newrelic_moped'
```

I have had similar problem in the past when I upgraded to Mongoid 3, but back then the solution was newrelic_moped. Not this time it seems.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same. Add the code below to `config/initializers/newrelic.rb`:

```
# Ensure the agent is started using Unicorn.
# This is needed when using Unicorn and preload_app is not set to true.
# See https://newrelic.com/docs/ruby/no-data-with-unicorn
if defined? Unicorn
  ::NewRelic::Agent.manual_start()
  ::NewRelic::Agent.after_fork(:force_reconnect => true)
end
```